# unique random id

Tags: php, global-variables, scope

I am generating unique id for my small application but I am facing some **variable scope** problem. my code-

```
function create_id()
{  
global $myusername;  
$part1 = substr($myusername, 0, -4);  
$part2 = rand (99,99999);  
$part3 = date("s");  
return $part1.$part2.$part3;  
}

$id;  
$count=0;

while($count == 1)  
{  
$id;  
$id=create_id();  
$sqlcheck = "Select * FROM ruser WHERE userId='$id';";  
$count =mysql_query($sqlcheck,$link)or die(mysql_error());  
}  


echo $id;
```

I dont know which variable I have to declare as `global`

Comment: there's a lot of problems with that code

Comment: You getter better with practice though :)

Comment: curious, what's wrong with auto_increment?

Comment: it seems like his intent is to obfuscate the unique ID for some reason.  auto_inc would not obfuscate.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't look like a variable scope problem, it looks like a simple variable assign problem:

```
$count=0;
while($count == 1)
{
```

This block will clearly never execute.

Further, please use a boolean with a good name when doing boolean checks. It reads so much cleaner. i.e.:

```
function isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck)
{
    $sqlcheck = "Select * FROM user WHERE userId='$userIDToCheck';";  
    $resource = mysql_query($sqlcheck)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
    if( count($count) > 0)
    {return false;}

    return true;
}


$userIDVerifiedUnique = false;
while(! $userIDVerifiedUnique )
{
     $userIDToCheck = create_id();
     $userIDVerifiedUnique = isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck );
}
```

Note that mysql_query will use the last used connection if you don't specify a link:
https://www.php.net/mysql_query
No need to make it global.

Comment: Why you want to create unique ID's this way I have no idea... maybe because later you want to set a cookie that is hard to guess? Better to just use the sessionID functionality already built in... Further, you should probably read the php session security section in the docs:
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Comment: **Fatal error:** Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\303\rand.php

Comment: ok, what is your first thought on how to find out why this is taking more than 60 seconds? Why don't you post a new question that explains what you are doing and the problem you are encountering. Include your new full source code for the page. This will give you an opportunity for some new rep on a new question also.

Answer (score 3):

in adition to Zak's answer i'd pass the username into the function instead of using globals

```
function create_id($username)
{
    $part1 = substr($username, 0, -4);  
    $part2 = rand (99,99999);  
    $part3 = date("s");  
    return $part1.$part2.$part3;  
}
```

also

```
//$id;  no need for this
$count=1; // this bit

while($count == 1)   // not sure what's going on
{  
//$id; again same thing  no need for this
$id=create_id($myusername);
```

**edit:** now that i think of it: how do you  expect to find `"Select * FROM ruser WHERE userId='$id';"`? A Select query is used to find something specific, your username is so random, i think the likely hood of actually successfully getting a record is 1 in a bajillion.
**edit2** whoops, i see the whole point is to get a unique username... O_O

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the others:

```
$count =mysql_query($sqlcheck,$link)or die(mysql_error());
```

mysql_query doesn't return a record count but, rather, a resource.

[mysql_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)