# never ending loop : fatal error

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

**my code-**

```
function create_id()
{  
    //global $myusername;  
    $part1 = substr("Piyush", 0, -4);  
    $part2 = rand (99,99999);  
    $part3 = date("s");  
    return $part1.$part2.$part3;  
}

echo create_id();  //this is printing fine.

function isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck)    
{
    $sqlcheck = "Select * FROM ruser WHERE userId='$userIDToCheck';";    
    $resource = mysql_query($sqlcheck)or die(mysql_error());   
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);  
    if( count($count) > 0)  
    {return false;}  

    return true;  
}


$userIDVerifiedUnique = false;  
while(! $userIDVerifiedUnique )  
{  
    $userIDToCheck = create_id();  
    $userIDVerifiedUnique = isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck );  
}
```

**loop is just going on and on from while loop to function `IsUniqueUser()` and vice versa.**????

Comment: When mysql_fetch_assoc() doesn't find rows to return, it returns false. count( false ) will return 1 since false is technically 1 element.

The isUniqueUserID function needs to be refactored as the answer below indicates.

Comment: PLEASE accept answers to your questions and please vote up good answers (at least to your own questions if not on the site at large).

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851003/unique-random-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try changing your `isUniqueUserID()` function to this

```
function isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck)
{

$userIDToCheck = mysql_real_escape_string($userIDToCheck); //prevent SQL injection

$sqlcheck = "Select userId FROM ruser WHERE userId='$userIDToCheck';";
$resource = mysql_query($sqlcheck)or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($resource);

return ($count > 0) ? false : true;
```

There's no point in returning an associative array just to count the number of rows in it. And there's no point in doing a `SELECT *` when counting just do `SELECT userId` since that's all you're concerned with.

I don't see any other reason that `isUniqueUserID()` would return false unless your `ruser` table has every possible ID.

Comment: Or `"select count(*) FROM ruser WHERE userId='$userIDToCheck';";` and please fix the sql injection risk if `$userIDToCheck` comes from user input

Comment: `select count(*)` would also work, but i would still do `select count(userId)` to prevent from selecting everything in the row. and i added a line to prevent sql injection

Comment: `count(*)` is idiomatic SQL and shouldn't ever need to read the full row unless there is something terribly wrong with your DBMS. It should be the preferred form.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no rows returned from the MySQL query (i.e. the `$userIDToCheck` is not in the table, it is unique) then `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return `FALSE`.  When that happens, `count(FALSE)` returns `1` (one)! Since that value is greater than zero the function returns `FALSE`.

In short, if there is a row returned (the string is not unique) your `isUniqueUserID` function returns `FALSE`; if there is no row returned (the string is unique) it still returns `FALSE`.

---

A simple, new, function to check on the database table could look something like the following...

```
function isUniqueUserID($userIDToCheck)
{
    $userIDToCheck = mysql_real_escape_string($userIDToCheck); // Assume not already escaped
    $sqlcheck = "SELECT 1 FROM ruser WHERE userId='$userIDToCheck' LIMIT 1";    
    $resource = mysql_query($sqlcheck) or die(mysql_error());
    return (bool) mysql_num_rows($resource);  
}
```

Comment: thats what I know then what changes I have to make??that was my Q.

Comment: @Piyush, see the function in my answer... though I notice you've accepted the other one. P.S. Your Q didn't ask what changes need to be made.